# Including external javascript into html site for Windows 10 Iot core Webserver

Tags: javascript, c#, html, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I am new to this forum and after some long investigations i still couldn't find my answer. 
I am currently developing a Local Webserver for Windows 10 IoT with the raspberry pi 3. I managed to implement a code that opens a html-side that i can see in my Webbrowser.  I want to use an external Javascript that dynamically gets the Values from my c# program and posts them on my Website.
The Problem is, that i can only use my Javascript code directly in my html-code. It seems like the directory of the javascript file isn't resolved within my Html-Code.

Html-Code not working:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <!--<script>
        window.onload = function ()
        {
            document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = function ()
            {
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML += "You have clicked once! <br>";
            }
        }
    </script>-->
    <link href="Website/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <button id="myBtn">Click Me!</button>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript-Code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML += "You have clicked once! <br>";
  };
};
```

Html-Code Working:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!--<script src="index.js"></script>-->
    <script>
        window.onload = function ()
        {
            document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = function ()
            {
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML += "You have clicked once! <br>";
            }
        }
    </script>
    <link href="Website/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <button id="myBtn">Click Me!</button>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

For now I use this code for test purposes. The javascript code gets hopefully filled with values as soon as I manage to call it from within my Html-code.

Both files are allocated in the same folder on the Raspberry. If Any further information is needed please feel free to ask.

Thank you in advance for all the help i might resive for my problem.

Comment: can you show us the file hierarchy containing these files?  Does the CSS load?